# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

```
Ca  Tên NVNL    Check in    Check out   Thời gian làm việc trong ca     Hỗ trợ ăn trưa
0   Ca Sáng     Ngô Hải Anh     08:15:00    12:13:00    NaN     NaN
1   Ca Chiều    Ngô Hải Anh     14:00:00    17:35:00    NaN     NaN
2   Ca Chiều    Ngô Văn Ninh    13:30:00    17:57:00    NaN     NaN
3   Ca Chiều    Nguyễn Hoàng Anh    14:00:00    17:43:00    NaN     NaN
```

I want to subtract Check out to Check In column. By this code

> `data['Thời gian làm việc']= data['Check out '] - data['Check in']`

But i get this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time' Please help me.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(data['Check out ']) -pd.to_datetime( data['Check in'])`

Comment: Also perhaps have a look at `datetime.timedelta`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think here is possible convert values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html), but first cast to `string`s:

```
data['Thời gian làm việc']= (pd.to_timedelta(data['Check out'].astype(str)) - 
                             pd.to_timedelta(data['Check in'].astype(str)))
```

Or to `datetimes` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
data['Thời gian làm việc']= (pd.to_datetime(data['Check out'].astype(str)) - 
                             pd.to_datetime(data['Check in'].astype(str)))
```

Comment: I had the same error and your solution worked. Thanks. Quick Question : how do i know that i need to convert it to string first before converting to timedelta or datetime ?

Comment: @IrfanHarun - check type of first value - if string, not necessary, else convert.

Comment: @IrfanHarun - `print (type(df.loc[0, 'data['Check out']']))`

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest you take a step back and think about your data model. A `time` is not a point in time, quoting from Python's documentation:

> A time object represents a (local) time of day, independent of any particular day

.. so substracting times doesn't make a lot of sense. Say I check in at 9pm and check out two days later at 8pm. What would you expect "8pm minus 9pm" to represent?

Your check in / check out columns would probably be better modeled as `datetime` which *do* represent points in time. Subtracting datetimes does work, and it has an actual meaning: the time which separates the two points in time.

Comment: No, check in and check out would be `datetime`. The *difference* between the two would be a `timedelta`.

Comment: Ya, agree. But if want use times for some reason, then better are timedelatas, which are support in pandas very nice, also is possible subtract.